# Записать значения дискретных каналов в бинарный файл. С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, binary, binary-file

Есть массив из значений дискретных каналов.

**int discretCh = 6;** // всего 6 дискретных каналов

Значения всегда будут либо 0 либо 1. Могут вообще быть только 0000000 либо 111111

**int ChValue [6] = {000011}**

в книге описано, как нужно записывать эти значения в бинарный файл.
Пример:

For a set of six status inputs (000011)

a) Write these status inputs as a binary number (110000).

b) Then pad the number out to a 16 bit number (0000 0000 0011 0000).

c) Translate this to a hexadecimal value (00 30).

d) The data is then stored in LSB/MSB format (30 00).

Важно, что от количества каналов зависит размер переменной, в которую записывается значение **(30 00)**

Нужно проверить

sizеVar = discretCh/16  округление в большую степень

if (sizеVar <= 1)
     2 байта для хранения

if (sizеVar > 1 || sizеVar = 2 )
    добавляем еще 2 байта

if (sizеVar > 2 || sizеVar = 3 )
    добавляем еще 2 байта

Все это я записываю в файл, строка должна получиться вида:

05 00 00 00 9B 02 00 00 08 FD FA 04 48 00 3D 00 74 FF 0A FE **30 00**

именно в последних 2х байтах я должна хранить дискретные значения.

Я вообще не понимаю, как это сделать((( Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Для начала вам нужно разобраться какого типа значения могут быть в каналах. Нутром чую, что либо 0, либо 1.

Comment: Да, конечно. Либо 0 либо 1.

Comment: Тогда начните с записи нужной битовой последовательности в целые числа: 2- 4- и 8-байтные. А не в массив.

Comment: у меня будет файл, из которого я буду брать значения этих каналов                                                                                             1,Раб МТЗ,,,0
2,3_3,,,0
3,8_8,,,0
4,8_100,,,0
5,3_8,,,0
6,3_8,,,0
7,29,,,0
8,41,,,0                                                                                                Вот эти нули в конце каждой строчки и есть значения

Comment: И вам все равно стоит писать значения каналов в целые числа. Даже если значения берутся из файла.

Comment: то есть каждое значение из массива должно храниться отдельно? допустим int ch1 = 1 и т.д.?

Comment: Вы вообще знаете что такое биты? Как они организованы в байты?

Comment: знаю, что в 1 байте 8 бит)

Comment: Уже неплохо. Что такое шестнадцетиричные числа, как производить перевод из двоичного числа в шестнадцетиричное при помощи calc.exe?

Comment: да, переводила при помощи калькулятора

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему 000011

a) Write these status inputs as a binary number (110000).

Comment: А я вот понять не могу, если единственный вопрос в "перевороте" битового представления - зачем все остальное в вопросе?

Comment: Как реализовать все это программно

Comment: Начинаем с начала: запись битовой последовательности в целое число.

Comment: 2 часа искала примеры, ничего( я хотела значения массива записать в целое число, но нули не записываются.        Вот еще вариант, допустим, если мои биты будут в строке string a = "000011";

    int b = atoi(a.c_str());
    return 0;                                            тоже нули не записываются(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат `LSB/MSB` - я исходил из того, что эта запись означает порядок байт от младшего к старшему (слева направо) и порядок бит от старшего к младшему (слева направо) при записи в бинарный файл.

> Важно, что от количества каналов зависит размер переменной, в которую записывается значение (30 00)

Скорее не размер переменной, а количество слов (16-ти битных чисел).

> For a set of six status inputs (000011)
>
> a) Write these status inputs as a binary number (110000).

Здесь имеется в виду что значения каналов записаны от наименее значимого к наиболее значимому, и в битовом представлении это как раз и будет `11000` (так как в битовом представлении самый правый бит самый младший, а самый левый бит - самый старший).

Таким образом у вас на входе есть массив дискретных значений каналов, причём на нулевой позиции массива записано значение самого младшего значения.

В C++ все числа хранятся в бинарном виде, вы можете только по разному их переводить в текстовое представление для вывода в консоль, к примеру. По разному - в разных системах счисления, в привычной всем со школы десятичной, или 16-ричной, 8-ричной.

Для работы с битами чисел обычно используют побитовые операции (побитовое `И` - `&`, побитовое `ИЛИ` - `|`) и битовые маски, а также битовые сдвиги (влево - `<<`, вправо - `>>`).

К примеру, чтобы получить значение некоторого (i-го) бита числа `X`, нужно получить маску - число, в котором i-ый бит выставлен в единицу, а остальные биты равны нулю, а потом выполнить побитовое `И` между исходным числом `X` и маской, после чего сдвинуть результат на `i` вправо (чтобы получить значение `0` или `1`)

```
int bitBalue(unsigned int X, int i){
    unsigned int mask = 0x1 << i; //двигаем единичный бит на i-ую позицию
    return (X & mask) >> i;
}
```

Подробнее можно посмотреть вот в этом [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990/3503216) из этого [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/3503216).

Числа, занимающие больше одного байта, могут физически храниться в памяти по разному - от младшего байта к старшему (`LittleEndian`), или от старшего к младшему (`BigEndian`).

К примеру, если записать число `1` в `unsigned short` (два байта), то на машине с `LittleEndian` порядком байт в памяти это число будет записано как 0x01 0x00 (по младшему адресу - младший байт), а на `BigEndian` машине - вот так: 0x00 0x01 (по младшему адресу - старший байт).

Это важно, так как от Вас требуется записать числа в файл в определённом формате (`LSB/MSB`), а для этого требуется знать в каком формате у Вас хранятся числа  в памяти.

Я взял [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4240014/3503216) из этого [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4239993/3503216), немножко его переделал и получил вот такой код для определения порядка байт на вашей машине.

```
using uint8_t = unsigned char;
using uint16_t =  unsigned short int;
using uint64_t = unsigned long long;

enum class Endian: uint8_t{
    BigEndian = 0,
    LittleEndian = 1
};

//  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4240014/3503216
Endian getEndian()
{
    uint16_t number = 0x1;
    uint8_t *numPtr = (uint8_t*)&number;
    return (static_cast<Endian>(numPtr[0]));
}
```

В итоге - мы можем манипулировать битами в числе, и знаем в каком порядке байты этого числа будут записаны в памяти.

Возьмём самое длинное число которое нам доступно (`unsigned long long`), запишем в него дискретные значения каналов (каждое значение в свой бит, первое значение в самый младший бит(нулевой, индексация с нуля), второе значение в следующий по старшинству бит (первый)), получим некоторое число.

Теперь нужно на основе количества каналов вычислить сколько двухбайтных (16-ти битных) слов  нам нужно записать.

```
int wordsCount = channelsCount / 16;
if (channelsCount %16)
    wordsCount++;
```

Для 17-ти каналов получим 2 слова, для 16 каналов - одно слово.

Дальше возьмём адрес нашего числа с записанными каналами и будет работать с ним как с указателем на массив байт, и в зависимости от порядка записи байт на нашей машине запишем эти байты в файл (не забывает что от нас требуется записать в файл сначала самый младший байт - `LSB/MSB`):

```
std::ofstream &BinaryChannels::out(std::ofstream &ofs) const
{
    int bytesCount = m_wordsCount * 2;
    const char* bytes = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&m_data);
    switch (getEndian()) {
    case Endian::LittleEndian: //в памяти число начинается с младшего байта
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesCount; i++){
            ofs.write(bytes + i, 1);
        }
        break;
    case Endian::BigEndian: // в памяти число начинается с старшего байта
        for (int i = bytesCount - 1; i >=0; i--){
            ofs.write(bytes + i, 1);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return ofs;
}
```

Я написал класс и пример:

```
int main()
{
    std::ofstream of("channels.dat", std::ios::binary);
    BinaryChannels b = {{0,0,0,0,1,1}};
    std::cout << "3rd bit of number 8: " << bitBalue(8,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2nd bit of number 8: " << bitBalue(8,2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    of << b;
    b = {1,0,1,0,0,1};
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    of << b;
    b = {
         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
        };
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    of << b;
    b = {
         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
        };
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    of << b;
    of.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
3rd bit of number 8: 1
2nd bit of number 8: 0
in hexadecimal: 0030
in hexadecimal: 0025
in hexadecimal: 00020100
in hexadecimal: 100804020100
```

Содержимое файла channels.dat:

```
30 00 25 00 00 01 02 00 00 01 02 04 08 10
```

Полный пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int bitBalue(unsigned int X, int i){
    unsigned int mask = 0x1 << i; //двигаем единичный бит на i-ую позицию
    return (X & mask) >> i;
}


using uint8_t = unsigned char;
using uint16_t =  unsigned short int;
using uint64_t = unsigned long long;

enum class Endian: uint8_t{
    BigEndian = 0,
    LittleEndian = 1
};

//  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4240014/3503216
Endian getEndian()
{
    uint16_t number = 0x1;
    uint8_t *numPtr = (uint8_t*)&number;
    return (static_cast<Endian>(numPtr[0]));
}

class BinaryChannels{
public:


    using DiscreteChannels = std::vector<int>;
    BinaryChannels();
    BinaryChannels(const DiscreteChannels& discreteChannels);
    BinaryChannels(const BinaryChannels& other);
    BinaryChannels& operator=(const BinaryChannels& other);
    BinaryChannels& operator=(const DiscreteChannels& discreteChannels);

    void resetChannels(const DiscreteChannels& discreteChannels);

    const uint64_t& channels() const;

    //вывод в формате LSB/MSB - байты с младшего к старшему,
    //биты с старшего к младшему
    std::ofstream& out(std::ofstream& ofs) const;
    //вывод в формате 16-ного числа (hexadecimal)
    std::ostream& out(std::ostream& os) const;


private:

    void setChannel(std::size_t idx, int channelValue);

    uint64_t m_data;
    int      m_wordsCount;
};

std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& f, const BinaryChannels& b){
    return b.out(f);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const BinaryChannels& b){
    return b.out(o);
}

int main()
{
    std::ofstream of("channels.dat", std::ios::binary);
    BinaryChannels b = {{0,0,0,0,1,1}};
    std::cout << "3rd bit of number 8: " << bitBalue(8,3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2nd bit of number 8: " << bitBalue(8,2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    of << b;
    b = {1,0,1,0,0,1};
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    of << b;
    b = {
         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
        };
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    of << b;
    b = {
         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
        };
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    of << b;
    of.close();
    return 0;
}

BinaryChannels::BinaryChannels():
    m_data{0x0},
    m_wordsCount{0}
{
}

BinaryChannels::BinaryChannels(
        const BinaryChannels::DiscreteChannels &discreteChannels):
    m_data{0x0},
    m_wordsCount{0}
{
    resetChannels(discreteChannels);
}

BinaryChannels::BinaryChannels(const BinaryChannels &other):
    m_data{other.m_data},
    m_wordsCount{other.m_wordsCount}
{}

BinaryChannels &BinaryChannels::operator=(const BinaryChannels &other)
{
    if (this !=&other){
        m_data = other.m_data;
        m_wordsCount = other.m_wordsCount;
    }
    return *this;
}

BinaryChannels &BinaryChannels::operator=(const BinaryChannels::DiscreteChannels &discreteChannels)
{
    resetChannels(discreteChannels);
    return *this;
}

void BinaryChannels::resetChannels(const BinaryChannels::DiscreteChannels &discreteChannels)
{
    m_data = 0x0;
    // больше 64 каналов в 64-х битное беззнаковое число не поместится
    std::size_t channelsCount = std::min(discreteChannels.size(), 64u);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < channelsCount; i++){
        setChannel(i, discreteChannels[i]);
    }
    // m_bytesCount = channelsCount / 16
    // if (channelsCount % 16){
    //     m_bytesCount++;
    // }
    m_wordsCount = channelsCount >> 4;
    if (channelsCount & 0xF){
        m_wordsCount++;
    }
}


const uint64_t &BinaryChannels::channels() const
{
    return m_data;
}


std::ofstream &BinaryChannels::out(std::ofstream &ofs) const
{
    int bytesCount = m_wordsCount * 2;
    const char* bytes = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&m_data);
    switch (getEndian()) {
    case Endian::LittleEndian: //в памяти число начинается с младшего байта
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesCount; i++){
            ofs.write(bytes + i, 1);
        }
        break;
    case Endian::BigEndian: // в памяти число начинается с старшего байта
        for (int i = bytesCount - 1; i >=0; i--){
            ofs.write(bytes + i, 1);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return ofs;
}

std::ostream &BinaryChannels::out(std::ostream &os) const
{
    os << "in hexadecimal: ";
    std::ios_base::fmtflags flags = os.flags();
    os.flags(std::ios::hex | std::ios::right);
    os.fill('0');
//    os.width(m_wordsCount*4);
    os.width(m_wordsCount<<2);
    os << m_data;
    os.flags(flags);
    return os;
}

void BinaryChannels::setChannel(std::size_t idx, int channelValue)
{
    uint64_t v = static_cast<uint64_t>(channelValue); //v in [0,1]
    int offset = static_cast<int>(idx);
    //выставляем бит по смещению idx
    v = v << offset;
    m_data = m_data | v;
}
```

Comment: Опишите подробнее, для чайника) по поводу сколько двухбайтных (16-ти битных) слов, процесс увеличения. Каналов может быть и 100, и 400.

Comment: @Yana для хранения каналов я использовал тип unsigned long long, у него размер - 8 байт, то есть 64 бита. И он может хранить до 64 каналов. Следовательно, если у Вас 100 каналов, то первые 64 канала вы храните в одном объекте класса BinaryChanels, а последние 36 каналов - в другом. Можете завести `std::vector<BinaryChannels> binChannels`, разбить исходные каналы по 64 штуки, и последовательно добавлять их в `binChannels`, после чего пройтись по вектору binChannels  и вывести каналы в файл.

Comment: @Yana Хотя правильнее наверное будет переписать `BinaryChannels`, и для хранения использовать не unsigned long long, а массив слов (unsigned short, 2 байта, 16 бит).

Comment: @Yana ну и ответ вроде бы достаточно подробный, изобилует ссылками и объяснениями большинства операций.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, описали все подробно, но что-то не доходит. сейчас буду разбираться.